# Clean way to handle file not found exception

Tags: python

**BACKGROUND**

I have a function where i cache file from aws s3. I provide it the path on s3 and also the local path of where i want the cached file to live. Sometimes if the file does not exist on s3 it will return a 404 error. That makes sense but i want to handle it gracefully. What i want to do is if the file i am trying to cache does not exist I want my get_overview_stream function to return None.

**CODE**

```
def get_overview_stream(*, environment, proxy_key):
    s3_overview_file_path = f"s3://{FOO_TRACK_BUCKET}/{environment}"
    overview_file = f"{proxy_key}.csv"
    local_path = cache_directory(environment)
    try:
        cache.cache_file(s3_overview_file_path, local_path, overview_file)
        overview_file_cache = local_path / f"{proxy_key}.csv"
        return overview_file_cache.open("r")
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404":
            return None
        else:
            raise
```

**Attempted Solution Issue**

I am very new to python so i am not sure if this the best way to handle this exception and if there is a more cleaner way. If so i would love to hear feedback.

Comment: Honestly, I've never used to libraries involved here, but I don't see anything wrong with this approach. The exception handling seems fine to me.

Comment: The only thing I would change here is adding a docstring and type information. You could move the last 2 lines in the try block outside. raising a custom exception instead of returning the sentinel value None might also be an improvement, but that last point id a matter of taste /habit

Comment: Also, always open a file with a context manager instead of a bare open()

Comment: @MaartenFabré can you show example of what you mean by custom exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not opening the file in your function but instead returning the path or `None`, such that the caller can open the file using a `with` statement.